# Is modifying an object's __dict__ to set its properties considered Pythonic?

Tags: python

I have a class that inflates objects from rows found in a database (or another source, e.g. MongoDB, a CSV file, etc.). To set the object's properties, it does something like `self.__dict__.update(**properties)` or `obj.__dict__.update(**properties)`.

Is this considered Pythonic? Is this a good pattern that I should continue to use, or is this considered bad form?

Comment: I don't know if it's Pythonic, but it's certainly more common to do it in dunder init.

Comment: Cf. [Is self.__dict__.update(**kwargs) good or poor style?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9728243) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 11):

In Python 3.3, a new type was added, [`types.SimpleNamespace()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace), and in the documentation it is described thus:

> The type is roughly equivalent to the following code:
>
> ```
> class SimpleNamespace:
>     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
>         self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
>     def __repr__(self):
>         keys = sorted(self.__dict__)
>         items = ("{}={!r}".format(k, self.__dict__[k]) for k in keys)
>         return "{}({})".format(type(self).__name__, ", ".join(items))
> ```

Note the `__init__` method of the type; you cannot get a better endorsement of the technique than the Python documentation.

Comment: Though `SimpleNamespace` is quite different from most types in that it doesn't have a fixed set of attributes.

Comment: Well, speaking of the Python documentation, from http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html "A special attribute of every module is `__dict__`. This is the dictionary containing the module’s symbol table. Modifying this dictionary will actually change the module’s symbol table, but direct assignment to the `__dict__` attribute is not possible (you can write `m.__dict__['a'] = 1`, which defines `m.a` to be 1, but you can’t `writem.__dict__ = {}`). _Modifying `__dict__` directly is not recommended_," which is what initially prompted me to ask this question.

Comment: @skyler: note that that only mentions the *module namespace*. The `globals()` function returns the same namespace, and there are usually better ways to solve problems than setting globals dynamically, hence the warning.